# Unable to add site column with jslink on SharePoint online with CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, csom, spfield

I'm facing a weird issue today, we have a SharePoint provider hosted add-in which used to work properly for the last year and a half.
In that SPPH Add-In we use jslink on fields. When we try to add a new site column with a jslink property specified we get an unknown error back.
If we try to create the field and then update it with the jslink value, same issue.
I tried updating the CSOM to the latest version too.
Anybody facing the same issue? Any idea on the subject?
Thanks for your help!

```html
web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field Type=\"Note\" Name=\"myfield\" StaticName=\"myfieldSN\" DisplayName=\"My FIeld\" " +
                                                       "Required=\"FALSE\" Hidden=\"FALSE\" ReadOnly=\"FALSE\" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary=\"TRUE\" " +
                                                       "ShowInDisplayForm=\"TRUE\" ShowInEditForm=\"FALSE\" ShowInListSettings=\"TRUE\" ShowInNewForm=\"FALSE\" " +
                                                       "ShowInVersionHistory=\"TRUE\" ShowInViewForms=\"TRUE\" ShowInFileDlg=\"FALSE\" " +
                                                       "Group=\"Attribute\" JSLink=\"sp.js|~sitecollection/SiteAssets/AttributeOnline/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js|~sitecollection/SiteAssets/AttributeOnline/Scripts/jslink.js 
\" />", false, AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);
            _context.Load(field);
            _context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related question : [PreSaveAction is not working in SharePoint office 365 (2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40738900/presaveaction-is-not-working-in-sharepoint-office-365-2016/40754714#40754714)

As stated in the documentation [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-classic-and-new-experiences-for-lists-and-document-libraries-30e1aab0-a5cc-4363-b7f2-09e2ae07d4dc) jslink is not yet supported in the new experience. In order to support your customization you'd have to disable it.